# For loop brackets

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class MultithreadingFour {
        public static void main(String args[]){
                A obj = new A();
                Task task= new Task();
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
                        Thread t= obj.newThread(task);
        }
}
```

Compilation error: Multiple markers at this line

```
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
  t cannot be resolved to a variable
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
Syntax error, insert ":: IdentifierOrNew" to complete ReferenceExpression
  Thread cannot be resolved to a variable
```

whereas

```
public class MultithreadingFour {
        public static void main(String args[]){
                A obj = new A();
                Task task= new Task();
                for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                        Thread t= obj.newThread(task);
                }
        }
}
```

compiles successfully (note the added curly braces in the `for` loop).

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 13):

In Java, a variable declaration `Thread t = ...` is technically not a statement, whereas a block `{ ... }` is. What follows `for ( ... )` must be a statement.

Answer (score 8):

The body of a "for statement" must be a "statement".

A local variable declaration is not a statement. So you can't put a local variable declaration as the "statement" of a "for statement".

Here is the allowed syntax of `for` loops :

> BasicForStatement:
>       for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) Statement
>
> ForStatementNoShortIf:
>       for ( ForInitopt ; Expressionopt ; ForUpdateopt ) StatementNoShortIf

You might want to read [JLS 14. Blocks and Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html) for more information.

Think to it, it would be illogical to allow a variable declaration in a one-line for loop as you can never access it because it is only available in the scope of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-Francois, it could have shown it as a warning, but y an error? eg: for(int i=0;i<10;i++) int y=i++;  though we are not using this value of y, still we are incrementing the value of i.

Comment: @user3689942 Jonathan Gibbons (developper of javac) answer this on an RPF already closed as "not an issue" where someone having this error tought it was a bug. *"Yes, it's slightly inconsistent, but that's the way the spec is, and javac conforms to the spec."*. As you can read, there is not really any specific reason. The specs are like that, and they follow the specs.

Comment: The RFP in question is https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8024336

Comment: @user3689942 If really you want to increment i, then simply write `i++`. It is the variable declaration that is not allowed.